# Error when installing Windows 8 SDK

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi

I'm trying to install the Windows 8 [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit). As requested by the installer, I uninstalled the Windows 7 SDK and than started the installation. The installer exits with an error:

> You must uninstall the Windows Software Development Kit before you can install the latest version of the kit.

What components do I need to uninstall except the Windows 7 SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not found the answer to this yet, the MSDN article *[Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx)* may help.

Comment: Unhelpful, no troubleshooting section there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. When the install of the Windows 8 SDK fails there will be a "Show log files" link visible. Click on that and then open the most recent log file. Search for the error you're seeing. There should be something in the log which says which component it found. (For me it was App Verifier.) Then go to Add/Remove Programs and uninstall that program. You should now be able to install the Windows 8 SDK.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The question was "which components do I need to uninstall to get the Windows 8 SDK to install" and I described how to find out which components are blocking the install. How does this not answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

I have Uninstall the current Windows Software Development Kit using Add/Remove Programs and then download the latest version from the MSDN site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx
and manage to install the Win SDK with no errors